# Using a global Variable inside a class

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I'm using android studio for a project api 21 minimum,
I have an activity with a textfield and a button, when click, I want the text of the textfield stored for the life of the application, I'm using a global variable for that.
I've got a class variable that extends Application:

```
package com.example.user.variableglobale;

import android.app.Application;


public class Variable extends Application {

private String chiffre;

public String getChiffre() {
    return this.chiffre;
}

public void setChiffre(String chiffre) {
    this.chiffre = chiffre;
}
```

inside my main :

```
   final Variable VG = (Variable) getApplication();
    final TestVar tV = new TestVar();

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tV.testVar(MainActivity.this);
            VG.setChiffre(String.valueOf(txt.getText()));
        }
    });
```

and here is the java class called with the button:

```
    public class TestVar {

    public void testVar(Context context) {
        Variable VG = (Variable) context.getApplicationContext();

        String temp = VG.getChiffre();

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "test java VG " + temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the way to use global variable inside java class?
When I click on the button, a toast appears with a "null" value for "temp" (seem to be not initialized).
In my example, I tried with "context", to no avail.

Comment: first thing to know: Java doesn't have global variables.

Comment: Define "life of the application"-the app may be stopped at any time by Android.

Comment: try with changed order 

   VG.setChiffre(String.valueOf(txt.getText()));
    tV.testVar(MainActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally it work, 
inside my onclickListener i have to swap declaration of variable and calling of my class... everything ok

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to store that ***variable*** would be to store it in shared preferences. You can access it in any activity and it persists even if app is closed.
You can use it withoud needing a **class** for **variable** like this.

main:

```
static final String CHIFFRE_KEY = "chiffre_key";
final TestVar tV = new TestVar();

btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(CHIFFRE_KEY, String.valueOf(txt.getText()));
        editor.commit();

        tV.testVar(MainActivity.this);
    }
});
```

and testVar method would look like this

```
public void testVar(Context context) {

    String vg = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(CHIFFRE_KEY);

    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "test java VG " + vg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can read more about Shared Preferences [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java)